# Make custom default page in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to add custom default page in Asp.net mvc so instead the page going to Home/Index , i would like to go to Account/Login. I have implement the following but it still go to Home/Index. Please advise what i did wrong. Thank you

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Custom",
            url: "{controller}/{Account}/{page}",
            defaults: new
            {
                category = UrlParameter.Optional,
                page = 1,
                action = "Login"
            },
                constraints: new
                {
                    controller = "Account"
                }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the case that you want the users to be redirected to the login page or a custom page if they are not 'signed-in'.

You could create a filter attribute.

example:

```
    [RequireHttps]
    [AuthorizationFilter]
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
    }


    public class AuthorizationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
        //do some validation, find if the user is signed-in.

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(..Some where in the site..);            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your route. The default route is set to /Home/Index

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters*
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

You can change that to be any route you wish

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters*
        new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ControllerActionName", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your default route (the last one) with this

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```